# Multilevel Model for Regression in STAN

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, stan

I have, for `N_countries` countries and for each day during a certain period, a list of purchases from my website and how much each purchase was. I think that money spent as a function of days since the start of this period follows a sigmoid:

$$y \sim \mathcal N\left(\frac{\alpha}{1 + e^{-(\beta\cdot day + \gamma)}} + \delta, \sigma\right)$$

I want to model this according to a hierarchical or multilevel model, in which $\alpha$ and $\delta$ are drawn from distributions whose hyperparametres are drawn from another distribution (my population level is the country). The way I did it is, however, *incredibly* computationally expensive:

```
data {
  int<lower = 1> N_people_day;
  int<lower = 1> N_countries;
  int<lower = 1, upper = N_countries> country[N_people_day];
  int<lower = 0> dsi[N_people_day];
  vector<lower = 0>[N_people_day] net_revenue;
}

parameters {
  // parametres
  vector<lower = 0>[N_countries] scale;                       // the sigmoid's scale parametre
  real<lower = 0> rate;                                       // rate parametre
  real<lower = 0> x_location;                                 // location parametre
  vector<lower = 0>[N_countries] y_location;                  // location parametre
  real<lower = 0> sigma;                                      // dispersion parametre

  // hyperparametres
  real<lower = 0> y_location_hyper_shape;
  real<lower = 0> y_location_hyper_rate;
  real<lower = 0> scale_hyper_shape;
  real<lower = 0> scale_hyper_rate;
}

transformed parameters {
  vector[N_people_day] mu;

  for(i in 1:N_people_day){
    mu[i] = scale[country[i]] / (1 + exp(-(rate * dsi[i] + x_location))) + y_location[country[i]];
  }
}

model {
  net_revenue ~ normal(mu, sigma);
  y_location ~ gamma(y_location_hyper_shape, y_location_hyper_rate);
  x_location ~ gamma(10, 0.5);
  scale ~ gamma(scale_hyper_shape, scale_hyper_rate);
}
```

I'm almost certain there's a better way to do it and that the biggest problem is that one `for` in the `transformed parameters` block. How should I do it instead, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can vectorise that like so:

```
mu = scale[country] ./ (1 + exp(-(rate * dsi + x_location))) + y_location[country];
```